# Should I specify value type in my function? JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, comparison, equals

I have read a lot about `==` vs `===` and seems that '===' is way to go (at least the more recommended) which also prevents some invalid values to be compared. So I have function like this:

```
$('#frm_filterby').on('change',changeAttr);
function changeAttr() {
    var elementVal = $(this).val();
    console.log(typeof elementVal) // outputs string
    switch(elementVal){
        case "1":
            $("#frm_search").attr({
                "type" : "text",
                "placeholder" : "Example: jcook56",
                "required" : true
            }).val("");
            break;
        case "2":
            $("#frm_search").attr({
                "type" : "email",
                "placeholder" : "example@gmail.com",
                "required" : true
            }).val("");
            break;
        case "3":
            $("#frm_search").attr({
                "type" : "number",
                "placeholder" : "Example: 103",
                "required" : true
            }).val("");
            break;
        default:
            $("#frm_search").attr({
                "type" : "text",
                "placeholder" : "Select Search Criteria",
                "required" : false
            }).val("");
    }
}
```

So function above uses `switch statement` to check which filter user selected and based on that will set the attributes in `search` input filed. So my question is should I use `Number()` or `parseInt()` and force `elementValue` to be numeric, also remove stings in case statements values and replace them with the numbers? Is that something that will change anything/prevent? Also I'm wondering if this same scenario is done with simple `if/else` statements where I would use `equal` would that be a good option? Example:

$('#frm_filterby').on('change',changeAttr);
    function changeAttr() {
        var elementVal = Number($(this).val());
        console.log(typeof elementVal) // outputs number

```
    if(elementValue === 1)
            $("#frm_search").attr({
                "type" : "text",
                "placeholder" : "Example: jcook56",
                "required" : true
            }).val("");
            break;
    }else if(elementVal === 2){
            $("#frm_search").attr({
                "type" : "email",
                "placeholder" : "example@gmail.com",
                "required" : true
            }).val("");
            break;
    }else if(elementVal === 3){
            $("#frm_search").attr({
                "type" : "number",
                "placeholder" : "Example: 103",
                "required" : true
            }).val("");
            break;
    }else{
            $("#frm_search").attr({
                "type" : "text",
                "placeholder" : "Select Search Criteria",
                "required" : false
            }).val("");
    }
}
```

I read few articles and they recommended using `===` when comparing values so in my case element value comes in the function as a string. In that case I have to convert the value to be Numeric in order to use `===` for comparison. If anyone has any thoughts about this please let me know.

Comment: 6 of 1 and half a dozen of the other. For supreme optimization, you would probably want to type them as Numeric because it would make the comparison quick but not by much and you wouldn't notice.

Comment: @AdamH Does that include switch statement as well or just if else?

Comment: The speed difference between if and switch is negligable at best. Go with what is easier for you, personally, to read and maintain later. For me, if it were more than say 3 if's i would change to switch because it's easier for me to read and follow. Remember, we write code for humans not computers so make sure its easy for you to read and follow and let the compiler worry about making it easy for the computer to read and understand.

Comment: Here is a quick example showing the performance difference between the patterns, keep in mind this changes from browser to browser and probably based on device too. https://jsperf.com/switch-case-vs-if-else/3

Comment: Related:  you should know the difference between `==` and `===` - not just "pick one" because the consensus is it's "the way to go".

Comment: @freedomn-m I'm not sure that I understand your comment? The better option is to use `===` and that's why I would like to do that.

Comment: No, the better option is the one that's appropriate to the situation.  Not just because, as you stated, "it *seems* it's the *way to go*".  Do you know **why** it's "the better option" or just using it blindly because it's recommended?

Comment: @freedomn-m It is better option since improves efficiency. If we define value to be numeric ahead of time JavaScript won't have to do automatic conversion for us. I did not say that using `==` is bad, I just see that `===` can improve some things. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`switch` cases are equivalent to `===`. If they weren't, this would work:

```
switch ( 1 ) {
    case '1':
        console.log('hi')
}
```

Converting `elementVal` to a number wouldn't make any difference. Your `if/else` version is also functionally the same (though the `break` statements don't do anything).